# How to decrypt of AES-256-GCM created with ruby in sjcl.js

Tags: ruby, encryption, aes, aes-gcm, sjcl

I'm trying to decrypt an AES cipher generated by Ruby with the sjcl.js library.

I'm getting a "corrupt" error for an unknown reason……. I want to fix the problem.

For reference, when encryption and decryption were attempted in CBC mode, decryption was successful.

Ruby Code:

```rb
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
iv = cipher.random_iv
cipher.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(password)
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final
return Base64.strict_encode64(iv) + Base64.strict_encode64(ciphertext)
```

Javascript Code:

```js
var iv = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(IV_BASE64);
var ciphertext = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(CIPHERTEXT_BASE64);
var key = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(KEY_UTF8);
var decrypted = sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt(new sjcl.cipher.aes(key), ciphertext, iv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES-GCM is an authenticated encryption algorithm. It automatically generates an authentication tag during encryption, which is used for authentication during decryption. This tag is *not* considered in the current Ruby code. It is 16 bytes by default, can be retrieved with `cipher.auth_tag` and must be added, e.g.:

```rb
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final + cipher.auth_tag
```

Regarding nonce/IV, note that Base64 encoding should actually be done *after* concatenation (which, however, is not critical for a 12 bytes nonce/IV commonly used with GCM).

---

On the JavaScript side the separation of the nonce/IV is missing. Ciphertext and tag do not need to be separated because the sjcl processes the concatenation of both (ciphertext|tag):

```js
const GCM_NONCE_LENGTH = 12 * 8
const GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16 * 8

// Separate IV and ciptertext/tag combination
let ivCiphertextTagB64 = "2wLsVLuOJFX1pfwwjoLhQrW7f/86AefyZ7FwJEhJVIpU+iG2EITzushCpDRxgqK2cwVYvfNt7KFZ39obMMmIqhrDCIeifzs="
let ivCiphertextTag = sjcl.codec.base64.toBits(ivCiphertextTagB64)
let iv = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(ivCiphertextTag, 0, GCM_NONCE_LENGTH)
let ciphertextTag = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(ivCiphertextTag, GCM_NONCE_LENGTH)

// Derive key via SHA256
let key = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash("my password")  

// Decrypt
let cipher = new sjcl.cipher.aes(key)
let plaintext = sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt(cipher, ciphertextTag, iv, null, GCM_TAG_LENGTH)
//let plaintext = sjcl.mode.gcm.decrypt(cipher, ciphertextTag, iv) // works also; here the defaults for the AAD ([]) and the tag size (16 bytes) are applied 
console.log(sjcl.codec.utf8String.fromBits(plaintext))
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sjcl/1.0.8/sjcl.min.js "></script>
```

The ciphertext used in the above code was generated with the Ruby code considering the authentication tag and is successfully decrypted.

Note that key derivation with a digest is insecure. Instead, a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2 should be used.

Comment: Aaaaah Thank you! I didn't know the authentication tag needed.